# How to access JSON Objects with spaces?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm trying to access the following output JSON and here's how I've done it:

```
https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=MSFT&apikey=demo

$string = file_get_contents("https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=MSFT&apikey=demo");

$json_b = json_decode($string, true);

echo $json_b['Time Series (Daily)']['2018-01-12']['4. close'];
```

This works fine. The problem is that I want to loop through several months of this data so I can't loop it as easily b/c of the middle object ['2018-01-12'], I want an easier way for my for loop to go through. The following does NOT work (say for accessing the 5th element in that time series array), but I want something similar.

```
echo $json_b['Time Series (Daily)'][4]['4. close'];
```

Is that possible?

Comment: What do spaces have to do with your question?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the following might offer a little guidance ~ notably the utility function ( `getitem` ) to get a specific item from the data

```
<?php
    $url='https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=MSFT&apikey=demo';
    $json=json_decode( file_get_contents( $url ), true );

    function pre($data=false,$header=false){
        if( $data ){
            $title = $header ? sprintf('<h1>%s</h1>',$header) : '';
            printf('%s<pre>%s</pre>',$title,print_r($data,1));
        }
    }

    function getitem( $obj, $key, $item ){
        return isset( $obj[ $key ] ) && isset( $obj[ $key ][ $item ] ) ? $obj[ $key ][ $item ] : false;
    }
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>JSON-Array-Data Loopity loop</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            $meta=$json['Meta Data'];
            $times=$json['Time Series (Daily)'];

            /* all close prices for last n days */
            $days=30;

            $dnow=new DateTime();

            foreach( $times as $key => $obj ){
                $dkey=new DateTime( $key );
                if( $dnow->diff( $dkey )->days < $days ){
                    printf('Close price: %s<br />', getitem( $times, $key, '4. close') );
                }
            }

            /* Get a specific record */
            echo getitem( $times, '2018-01-11', '5. volume' );

            /* show all of type '4. close' */
            foreach( $times as $key => $obj ){
                printf( '%s<br />', getitem( $times, $key, '4. close' ) );
            }

            /* show all records */
            foreach( $times as $key => $obj ){
                pre( $obj, $key );
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want exactly the 5th element of your array

```
$key = 4;
$target = array_slice($json_b['Time Series (Daily)'], $key,1);
echo key($target) . ' => ' . current($target)['4. close'];
```

[**demo**](https://eval.in/934482)

Comment: I want all the close prices for the past 30 days. Is the best way to do what you're suggesting, changing $key to numbers between 0-29 inside some for loop?

Comment: The output is: 2018-01-12 => 89.6000, how do I make the output just 89.6000?

Comment: remove `key($target) . ' => ' . ` from the echo line

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over an Object in PHP using `foreach` loop.

```
<?php
$string = '{
  "Meta Data": {
    "1. Information": "Daily Prices (open, high, low, close) and Volumes",
    "2. Symbol": "MSFT",
    "3. Last Refreshed": "2018-01-12",
    "4. Output Size": "Compact",
    "5. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
  },
  "Time Series (Daily)": {
    "2018-01-12": {
      "1. open": "88.6700",
      "2. high": "89.7800",
      "3. low": "88.4500",
      "4. close": "89.6000",
      "5. volume": "24260921"
    },
    "2018-01-11": {
      "1. open": "88.1300",
      "2. high": "88.1300",
      "3. low": "87.2400",
      "4. close": "88.0800",
      "5. volume": "16529868"
    }}}';

$json_b = json_decode($string, true);

foreach( $json_b as $key => $value ){
    echo $key."\n";
}
```